# Create Expression from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression-trees

I'm using an API that expects an `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, and uses this to create mappings between different objects:

```
Map(x => x.Id).To("Id__c"); // The expression is "x => x.Id"
```

How can I create the necessary expression from a `PropertyInfo`? The idea being:

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

foreach (var propInfo in properties)
{
    var exp = // How to create expression "x => x.Id" ???

    Map(exp).To(name);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need `Expression.Property` and then wrap it in a lambda. One tricky bit is that you need to convert the result to `object`, too:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(x);
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propInfo);
var conversion = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, parameter);
Map(lambda).To(name);
```

Comment: Thanks, did exactly what I needed it to.

Comment: Is actually "var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propInfo);"